# MSIX Packaging tool: The package doesn't contain any Application elements in the app manifest file

Tags: msix

So I used the MSIX Packaging tool to generare a MSIX file from an existing .msi file.

This .msi files accesses a card reader to read a card. There is no GUI as the .msi is accessed from an Edge/Chrome Plugin.

When uploading the .msix to the Microsoft partner center I get following error:

> Package acceptance validation error: The package
>   ...__xctw132twwrd0_1.msix doesn't contain any Application elements in
>   the app manifest file.

How can I solve this? I can manually modifiy the manifest file but what to change/add ?

Comment: There's something here about elements on this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests but I'm stuck as to what to do. Maybe someone more versed in this could help with this info.